# Editing LibreOffice .odt in Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

Is there any way to edit an `.odt` file directly in Google Docs which was created with LibreOffice Writer and uploaded to Google Drive whilst preserving the ODT format and not converting it to Google Docs format to avoid losing formatting?

Comment: @rink.attendat.6 Thanks for your review! I just realised that indeed it was hard to understand what I actually want.

Answer (score 4):

It's now supported! I've just successfully opened an `.odt` document and edited it with Google Docs.

When you first open the file, you get a preview:

[image]

Now just click `Open` and it will open it in Google Docs.

Answer (score 3):

The online editor only supports Google Docs (`.gdoc`) format.

You can import from `.odt` by:
1. enabling ["Upload Settings"](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2424101?hl=en) > "Convert uploaded files to Google Docs format"
2. Right clicking an uploaded `.odt` and ["Open with"](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2424101?hl=en) Google Docs, a copy of `.gdoc` will be created

You can also "Download as odt".
Indeed the formatting are not 100% compatible and that causes issues.
Or maybe someone could develope an live editor for `.odt` as Drive connected app these days.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry no, Google stopped supporting .odt around 2005.

Comment: Do you have blue eyes? Please add a reference and then I will take your word for that...